# Calculation of % of GC time in Java server

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, jvm

I am using **jstat** to get the total accumulated time for GC operations, i.e. **GCT**

So, assume GCT is 2 seconds, and my JVM process started for 60 seconds, am I an running on Quad Core sever, so my % of GC is

```
2 / 60 * 4 = 0.83%
```

Is my calculation above correct?

Answer (score 6):

No, your calculation is not precise, because this way, you don't know the exact time for which the OS allowed your program to run.

Assuming that you want to consider the time for which the application was completely stopped by the GC (pause time), you can use the following JVM options:

```
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
```

This options will make the JVM print something like this to stdout:

```
Application time: 3.3319318 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.7876304 seconds
Application time: 2.1039898 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.4100732 seconds
```

You can then sum up the times for which the application was stopped and divide it by the sum of application time plus the pause time to get the mutator utilization (fraction of time in which the application was not paused by GC).

See also http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2008/02/18/measuring-the-time-an-application-was-stopped-due-to-garbage-collection/

Comment: do you know where the docs for those arguments are? is application time wall time or cpu time?

Comment: @radai Good question - I am not exactly sure, but I will try to find it out and update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

no, not really. your calculation assumes 100% utilization of all 4 cores by the java processes during the whole time.

the correct calculation is `(time spent in logic) / (time spent in gc)` but getting the 1st piece of information usually requires a profiler.

Comment: That make sense, but is it possible to retrive the value of `time spent in logic` using jstat or other tools? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[PrintGCDetails](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/the_unspoken_cms_and_printgcdetails) - this option could be helpful. It prins information about every garbage collection.

```
[GC
[PSYoungGen: 99952K->14688K(109312K)]
422212K->341136K(764672K), 0.0631991 secs]
[Times: user=0.83 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
```

> Pprovides CPU usage and elapsed time information. The value to the
>   right of user is the CPU time used by the garbage collection executing
>   instructions outside the operating system. In this example, the
>   garbage collector used 0.06 seconds of user CPU time. The value to the
>   right of sys is the CPU time used by the operating system on behalf of
>   the garbage collector. In this example, the garbage collector did not
>   use any CPU time executing operating system instructions on behalf of
>   the garbage collection. The value to the right of real is the elapsed
>   wall clock time in seconds of the garbage collection. In this example,
>   it took 0.06 seconds to complete the garbage collection.

[Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528) - good book, could be found in digital version. Contains a great article about measuring GC's impact.

Comment: THanks, I am using `PrintGCDetails` but it only tell me the GC time, I want to know the percentage for comparison.

Comment: Theats a very strange purpose, saying honestely. Why not just minimize GC time against same test case by playing with GC types and generation sizes.

Answer (score 1):

No, the calculation is not correct. What you *want* to calculate is

```
( CPU spent on GC ) / ( total CPU spent on JVM)
```

As pointed out in the other comments, the "total CPU spent on JVM" will be lower than 60*4, as that assumes full system load by your application and no CPU cycles spent by the operating system or by other applications. On linux, the "time" and "ps" commands can be used to find out the proper number here.

However, also the "CPU spent on GC" is difficult to find out by the jstat command. I suspect that jstat reports wallclock times (and not CPU times), which will be useless for the calculation above -- again, you don't know whether GC fully loaded all cores during the wallclock time period. Surprisingly, there's no clear documentation on what kind of time (wallclock vs. CPU) is reported by the jstat command -- if I missed that, please leave a comment here.